# How to call Retrofit in dobackground (AysncTask class)

Tags: android, retrofit

I recently switched to Retrofit, and very new to the retrofit concepts. I found out about it [Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/) and found it very interesting and made my work more easier and simpler.

As per the rules any HTTP request must be in a AsyncTask extended class,
 from the above tutorial I found that the retrofit call are made in the main UI thread itself.

I am finding it difficult to implementing the same tutorial in a AsyncTask class. How can I do this?

please help me as for every retrofit call my app is betting slower and I get skip frames 1076.

Comment: Retrofit already does http requests in a background thread for you!

Comment: And that's `enqueue` method

Comment: Maybe you're calling `execute` method, it runs on the main thread and blocks it until the task is done

Comment: What is the use of using retrofit if you are going to use asyntask? It was actually meant to replace asynctask

Comment: @FarShaD I did everything exactly as it is in the    [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/). and all the interfaces for retrofit are using `enqueue`. Even then i get the skip frames above 50 always

Comment: If you are getting that message, then Retrofit isn't the problem. Please close this question if you are using `enqueue` and make a new one with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 methods in retrofit2, First is execute that will call the request synchronously. The second is enqueue method that will make the request asynchronously.

Comment: so what ever i have used looking in the tutorial is right according to you?

Answer (score 0):

> As per the rules any HTTP request must be in a AsyncTask extended class

You misunderstand - A network request *cannot be run on the UI thread*. An AsyncTask just happens to be one way to do that. Retrofit/OkHttp is another, and Volley, and AsyncHttpClient are others.

> I am finding it difficult to implementing the same tutorial in a AsyncTask class

Probably that is because that tutorial is specifically for Retrofit?

> How can I do this?

A high-level overview of what Retrofit gives you that you would have to toss together in an AsyncTask

- Building an HTTP Request
- Adding HTTP Headers (if needed)
- Reading an InputSteam to a String
- String to JSON conversion
- JSON to Java Object Conversion
- Callbacks to the main thread

Now, that all seems complex if you don't really understand that stuff. That being said, you should just stick to Retrofit's `enqueue`